# Is IIT consciousness theory a pseudo science?

Tags: intelligence, cognitive-science

[Nature writes](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02971-1)

> It [a letter] argues that a prominent theory describing what makes someone or something conscious — called the integrated information theory (IIT) — should be labelled as pseudoscience.

> in addition, Lau says, some of his co-authors think that it’s not possible to empirically test IIT’s core assumptions, which they argue contributes to the theory’s status as pseudoscience.

The article continues with rebuttal

> [Liad Mudrik],  “Not only did we test it, we managed to falsify one of its predictions,”

- Is IIT a pseudo science?

Comment: If a theory is "bacon cures cancer and COVID", and the prediction that it cures COVID is falsified, then the theory isn't pseudoscience ?!?

Comment: As this is an open argument in an emerging field, this question might be better suited to a scientific Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavePhD Given the context, I assume they're treating 'pseudoscience' as something that is untestable, or 'belief' based. In this case, a good-faith experiment that determined that bacon does not in fact cure cancer and COVID would still be science, albeit a bit silly.

Comment: YMMV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory#Reception As discussed there, most other theories of consciousness have roughly the same status. See also https://www.science.org/content/article/search-neural-basis-consciousness-yields-first-results

Comment: Careful of the false binary. If something is [not a pseudoscience] that doesn't mean it is a science.The Wikipedia article on IIT quotes John Searle as saying "it does not get up to the level of being false", a nice rephrase of "Not even wrong".